# Set mandatory output format and folder in graphic modeler

Tags: qgis-modeler, qgis-3

I'm working with the graphic modeler in QGIS3.2 Bonn. I have created some models and they work quite well. In order to make them more easy to use for others:

- Is it possible to set the output format of the result of a model mandatory to ods or shp format?
- And is it possible to set an output folder mandatory?

Comment: Not sure about mandatory but you could certainly make a default path so that the output will always be saved at a specific folder in a specific format. You can do this by clicking the ellipsis (...) in the final result parameter of your model.

Comment: Did you solve it ?